# RxAndroid onNext being called multiple times

Tags: retrofit2, rx-android

I am calling an api via retrofit with RxAndroid. Here's how the method is defined

```
@GET("product")
    Observable<BaseResponse<List<Product>>> getProducts(@Query("lang") String lang,
                                                        @Query("category_id") String category_id,
                                                        @Query("start") String start,
                                                        @Query("count") String count);
```

This api returns the list of `Product`. I wanted to process each Product object inside list to check if that product exists in local db & set the boolean in product object. So I did it like this,

```
public Observable<List<Product>> getProductList(String catId, int start, int count) {

        final List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        return RestClient.callApiWrapper(mContext, true, null,
                RestClient.get().getProducts("en", catId, "" + start, "" + count))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .flatMapIterable(new Func1<BaseResponse<List<Product>>, Iterable<Product>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Iterable<Product> call(BaseResponse<List<Product>> listBaseResponse) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "flatMapIterable called");
                        return listBaseResponse.getData();
                    }
                })
                .map(new Func1<Product, List<Product>>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<Product> call(Product product) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "map called => " + products.size());
                        products.add(checkIfProductAddedToCart(product));
                        return products;
                    }
                });

    }
```

I have subscribed to `getProductList` where I need the processed list in this way:

```
mProductListDataModel.getProductList(mCategoryId, mStartOffset, mCount)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Product>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<Product> products) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "onNext => " + products.size());
                        if(mOnProductListLoaded != null)
                            mOnProductListLoaded.onProductListLoaded(products);
                    }
                });
```

Now the problem is, the API actually returns list of 5 products, but `onNext` is being called 5 times each time with increasing size upto 40 products. Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed few things for now, which are as below which works for me:

changed `getProductList` to return `Product` instead of `List<Product>`
so it looks like

```
public Observable<Product> getProductList(String catId, int start, int count) {

        //final List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        return RestClient.callApiWrapper(mContext, true, null,
                RestClient.get().getProducts("en", catId, "" + start, "" + count))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .flatMap(new Func1<BaseResponse<List<Product>>, Observable<Product>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<Product> call(BaseResponse<List<Product>> listBaseResponse) {
                        return Observable.from(listBaseResponse.getData());
                    }
                })
                .map(new Func1<Product, Product>() {
                    @Override
                    public Product call(Product product) {
                        //Log.e("TAG", "map called => " + products.size());
                        //products.add(checkIfProductAddedToCart(product));
                        //return products;
                        return checkIfProductAddedToCart(product);
                    }
                });
    }
```

and changed following where this observable was subscribed:

```
final List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
    mProductListDataModel.getProductList(mCategoryId, mStartOffset, mCount)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Product>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {
                            Log.e("TAG", "onCompleted => " + products.size());
                            if (mOnProductListLoaded != null)
                                mOnProductListLoaded.onProductListLoaded(products);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(Product product) {
                            products.add(product);
                        }
                    });
```

However, I am still not sure if this is the right way of doing this. Please let me know if this is not the right way to do so.